# Allocating size of 1 dimensional array based on incoming list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of number I want to organize within a function. I want to store the even numbers from the list into another 1 dimensional array within the function and solely work with those numbers. However, I am struggling to find out how to do this. I'm pretty new to python so I'm sorry if there is a basic solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
even_list = [i for i in my_list if not i%2]
```